# R and/or data science folks: where’s the “tidy-data” tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was surprised to see that there’s a [tidyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tidyr) tag but no general [tidy-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tidy-data) tag (referring, of course, to Hadley’s [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) [PDF]). I’ve gone ahead and created it for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29350036/1968) since I thought it was a very good fit.

However, I’m wondering if this is generally a good tag. I thought so, especially for the purpose of searching. But given that it didn’t exist yet I’m wondering if there may be a reason why people didn’t use it yet. Maybe the concept of “tidy data” is less well known than I thought?

What do people think about such a tag? Pros? Cons? Should we tag questions with it? Or is there maybe a natural synonym for it?

Comment: There's no real point in guessing it it might be useful.  Time will tell either way.  Either people will follow it and use it on their questions, or they won't.  Any guesses we make as to whether it may or may not end up being used won't really matter.

Comment: @Servy Asking if there's any reason why it has yet to be implemented / if there is a synonymous tag already seems like a perfectly valid question though, doesn't it?

Comment: @DonkeyKong It doesn't exist because nobody felt the need to add it to any questions.  That's true of basically every single tag that doesn't exist.  If there is a synonym, then presumably someone will add it as one when they notice it.

Comment: @Servy It’s a pretty commonly used term in the R community though (at least recently). Hence my question **why** it doesn’t exist yet, since it seems to me that it should obviously exist.

Comment: @KonradRudolph There are millions of commonly used terms that are some way related to programming.  Not every single term needs to have its own tag.  If people think it would be a useful tag, they'll use it, if they don't, they won't.  Either way, us taking about it accomplishes nothing.  We can say its useful all we want, but if people don't use the tag, that's all that matters.  Conversely, if we feel that a tag isn't useful, but people start using it, then apparently it was useful.  What we think of the tag is simply irrelevant.

Comment: I'm even more surprised that it's not a tag on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) either.

Comment: It appears to be a re-invention (really only an acknowledged re-labeling) of the notion of Codd's normal forms. Don't we have terminology to cover that already?

Comment: @42- Close enough, but as you may know different fields use different terminology and it's more, not less, confusing to use nonstandard terminology.